# How to improve the following code

Tags: c#, asp.net

If there is a possibility of improving the following code I will love it.

I have to DropDownList on my page (showing every category), one to filter the posts and one to create a new post. This is the code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlCategory.DataSource = BindDDlCategory();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlCategory.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlCategory.DataValueField = "Id";
            }
            ddlCategory.DataBind();

            if (ddlCategory.Items.Count == 0)
                ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Não há nenhuma categoria cadastrada", "108", true));
            else
                ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Todas as categorias", "108", true));

            ddlCategoryNP.DataSource = BindDDlCategory();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlCategoryNP.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlCategoryNP.DataValueField = "Id";
            }
            ddlCategoryNP.DataBind();
            if (ddlCategoryNP.Items.Count == 0)
                ddlCategoryNP.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Não há nenhuma categoria cadastrada", "108", true));
            else
                ddlCategoryNP.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Escolha uma categoria", "108", true));
        }
```

The method BindDDlCategory is:

```
protected DataTable BindDDlCategory()
        {
            Read readCategoryNP = new Read();
            return readCategoryNP.Category();
        }
```

The readCategoryNP shows me the DataTable on my database.

Comment: You should use code review for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn`t knew about code reviews. My mistake. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to repost on [CodeReview.se], please be sure to include working code, and some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Kemal this should be on code review. Here's my 2 cents:

```
-- your code, reduced
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var dataSource = BindDDlCategory();
    PrepareDDL(ddlCategory, dataSource);
    PrepareDDL(ddlCategoryNP, dataSource);
}

-- new method
private void PrepareDDL(DropDownList ddl, DataTable dataSource)
{
    ddl.DataSource = dataSource;
    ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddl.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddl.DataBind();

    string message = ddl.Items.Count
        ? "Não há nenhuma categoria cadastrada"
        : "Todas as categorias";
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(message, "108", true));
}

-- and the existing method
protected DataTable BindDDlCategory()
{
    return new Read().Category();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 blocks of code in your method doing the binding that are identical apart from the ddl that is being operated on. Why not create a method that takes a ddl as an argument, then applies the binding to it. DRY :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```csharp
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     BindCategory();
}

protected void BindCategory()
{
    ddlCategory.DataSource = BindDDlCategory();
    ddlCategory.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlCategory.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlCategory.DataBind();

    string aditionalItem = (ddlCategory.Items.Count == 0) ? "Não há nenhuma categoria cadastrada" : "Todas as categorias"   
    ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(aditionalItem, "108", true));

    //since both are equas, bind here in order to avoid calling BindDDlCategory() again:
    ddlCategoryNP.DataSource = BindDDlCategory();
    ddlCategoryNP.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlCategoryNP.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlCategoryNP.DataBind();
    ddlCategoryNP.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(aditionalItem, "108", true));    
}
```